# Dc Replication issue when on one of the Dc moved to another location

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

We have one Domain controller in Dallas office and other 2 in Chicago.
An administrator in Chicago moved 1 domain controller to Salt lake, now the problem starts here Chicago location and salt lake can communicate with each other, But the domain controller in Dallas cannot communicate with salt lake but it can communicate with Chicago Domain controller. Can it be resolved via Ad sites and services.?

Comment: What do you mean the Domain Controller was moved? Do you mean that it was physically moved?

Answer (score 1):

It will be necessary to set up a new site for Salt Lake in AD Sites and Services, which you have probably already done. You'll then need to create and assign a subnet to the site and make sure that connectors are set up in AD Sites and Services to replicate between all DCs. With that simple setup you'll be fine with connectors from all DCs to each other.

Once that's done ensure that the DNS settings (in the adapter settings) of each DC still valid addresses, and that none of them are using the now dead IP address in Chicago as a DNS server, and in the DNS server settings on each host make sure all the records that had the old IP are updated to the new IP. That should be enough to get it working. You may find you have to wait a while for it to come good, or you can try forcing replication.

This article also has the steps that should have been taken to move the DC, as a reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794722%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Another method if it's an option (sounds like it's not) is to demote the Salt Lake domain controller, wait for AD to replicate between Chicago and Dallas, confirm that the DC is gone from AD, and then promote the Salt Lake server to a DC again.

Comment: Worth pointing out that while a good idea (for multiple reasons), setting up a new ADDS site should not be required for replication between domain controllers.  Should help the KCC service auto-generate the required replication links, but this relies on assumptions that may not be safe... when the asker can't even clarify what is meant by "moved a DC", I don't think it's wise to assume that things are being setup or done even remotely properly.  (I mean really, who *moves* a domain controller anymore anyway?  It's not NT 4.0, the easier, safer way is to promote a new one.)